# python - Not Found The requested URL was not found on the server

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pycharm

I am new to Python web programming, I created a small program. But everytime I run, I am getting this error, `The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.`

This is my code below

Sample.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/profile/<name>")
def profile(name):
    return render_template("profile.html", name=name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

profile.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Welcome to thefunnybone</title>
<h1>Hey there, {{name}}</h1>
```

Description:
I am writting a name in the url, and it returns some text on the browser.

As said earlier, I am new to this language, therfore, please help me that I could provide any info regarding the program.

This is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: Please post the traceback and let us know where the files are in the tree.

Comment: And show us what URL you went to when you got this error.

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/profile/Sarthak"   this is the URL @DanielRoseman

Comment: Please post the directory-file structure

Comment: @amulya349  I have inserted the project structure image.

Comment: @NehaBeniwal Check my answer

Comment: See the answers from me and @amulya349

Answer (score 0):

Your url : `127.0.0.1:5000/profile/Sarthak`
seems to be correct. 
I think you might have put the `HTML` file in the same directory as the `Sample.py`.

By default flask application searches for templates in `templates` directory. To make it work, create a templates directory and put the html file inside it. No need to change the python code. It will work.

You can refer to this directory structure:

```
/Sample.py
/templates
    /profile.html
```

Refer to this link:
[Flask Templates Guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#rendering-templates)

Answer (score 0):

OK I tested this code: it works provided the file tree is right. You need a directory (folder) in the same directory as you program file containing the template file, this directory must be called 'templates'

Comment: you mean templates/templates/profile.html ??? Do I have to create another folder with the same name as 'templates'?

Comment: NO I mean src/package1/templates. static should also be there.

Comment: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NbgK.jpg"   Please follow the link for the file structure.